# Grails 2.4 Guice Bug

Tags: grails, guice, grails-plugin

I have seen several articles (such as [GRAILS-11503 JIRA - scroll to the bottom](https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-11503)) that indicate that Grails uses its own version of Google Guice - an elusive "3.1.0" version.

However:

- I see no 3.1.0 Guice JAR published to Maven/Grails Central; and
- When I do a `grails dependency-report` I do not see "guice" occur anywhere in the output

So I ask: **Is it true that Grails has its own Guice version? If so, where is it published, and why don't I see it when I run `grails dependency-report`?**

I ask because the solution posted in GRAILS-11503 (add the `exclude` clause to a dependency, hence excluding the dependency's version of Guice so as not to conflict with Grails' version) worked on my Grails 2.3.6 app. But now I am **upgrading to 2.4.4** and suddenly that fix is no longer working, and I'm getting bizarro Guice exceptions when running `grailsw publish-plugin`:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class com.google.inject.internal.UntargettedBindingProcessor$1 from class com.google.inject.internal.UntargettedBindingProcessor
    at com.google.inject.internal.UntargettedBindingProcessor.visit(UntargettedBindingProcessor.java:35)
    at com.google.inject.internal.UntargettedBindingProcessor.visit(UntargettedBindingProcessor.java:27)
    at com.google.inject.internal.BindingImpl.acceptVisitor(BindingImpl.java:93)
    at com.google.inject.internal.AbstractProcessor.process(AbstractProcessor.java:56)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorShell$Builder.build(InjectorShell.java:184)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalInjectorCreator.build(InternalInjectorCreator.java:104)
    ...huge stack trace omitted for brevity
    at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:591)
    at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:590)
    at org.grails.wrapper.GrailsWrapper.main(GrailsWrapper.java:93)
```

Comment: Does the answer I gave help at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't use Grails or Maven, but I downloaded the latest Grails binary (2.4.4) from the official homepage: https://grails.org/download.html

Inside that archive there is `/lib/org.sonatype.sisu/sisu-guice/jars/sisu-guice-3.1.0-{...}.jar`

It looks like you can get there through Maven links via following deps:

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.grails/grails-aether/2.4.4

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.aether/aether-impl/1.0.0.v20140518

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.sonatype.sisu/sisu-guice